# Plantuml generates interface from Doxygen group

Tags: doxygen, plantuml, doxygen-addtogroup

I would like to generate an interface diagram using Plantuml in Doxygen. Instead of typing the interfaces one by one as below, is it possible to generate the interface from the Doxygen group? I have created a group called "ExportInterface".

```
@startuml
interface "interface.h" as interface
{
  function1(void): void
  function2(void): void
  function3(void): int
}
@enduml
```

**doxygen -x Doxyfile**

```
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.9.1 (ef9b20ac7f8a8621fcfc299f8bd0b80422390f4b)
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ms
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        = .
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    = .
ALIASES                = "project=\par Project: \n" \
                         "subsystem=\par Subsystem: \n" \
                         "history=\par History: \n\htmlonly <pre>" \
                         endhistory=</pre>\endhtmlonly \
                         "startuml{1}=\image html \1\n\image latex \1\n\if DontIgnorePlantUMLCode" \
                         enduml=\endif \
                         "xrefreq{2}=@ref \1 \"\1\" @anchor \1 <a href='\2' target='_blank'>Requirements Object Link</a>\n" \
                         "satisfyreq{2}=@xrefitem satisfy \"Satisfies requirement\" \"Requirement Satisfaction\" @xrefreq{\1,\2}" \
                         "verifyreq{2}=@xrefitem verify \"Verifies requirement\" \"Requirement Verification\" @xrefreq{\1,\2}" \
                         "xrefarc{2}=@ref \1 \"\1\" @anchor \1 <a href='\2' target='_blank'>Containing Rhapsody Model</a>\n" \
                         "xrefarc_path{3}=@ref \1 \"\2\" @anchor \1 <a href='\3' target='_blank'>Containing Rhapsody Model</a>\n" \
                         "tracearc{2}=@xrefitem architecture \"Architecture\" \"Traced Architecture\" @xrefarc{\1,\2}" \
                         "tracearc_path{3}=@xrefitem architecture \"Architecture\" \"Traced Architecture\" @xrefarc{\1,\2,\3}" \
                         "startTraceIt{1}=<B>\anchor \1\nTraceIt data: \1</B><PRE>" \
                         endTraceIt=</PRE> \
                         "reftrace{1}=@anchor ref_\1 @ref \1" \
                         "reftrace{2}=@anchor ref\1_\2 @ref \2"
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = fidl=IDL
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = YES
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = NO
WARN_LOGFILE           = doxygen-build/warnings.log
INPUT                  = ../adapt \
                         ../core \
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
                         *.java \
                         *.ii \
                         *.ixx \
                         *.ipp \
                         *.i++ \
                         *.inl \
                         *.idl \
                         *.ddl \
                         *.odl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.cs \
                         *.d \
                         *.php \
                         *.php4 \
                         *.php5 \
                         *.phtml \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.markdown \
                         *.md \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox \
                         *.pyw \
                         *.f90 \
                         *.f \
                         *.for \
                         *.tcl \
                         *.vhd \
                         *.vhdl \
                         *.ucf \
                         *.qsf \
                         *.as \
                         and \
                         *.js \
                         *.fidl \
                         *.fdepl
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = *_Template.c
IMAGE_PATH             = images
FILTER_PATTERNS        = *.fidl=
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = NO
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = YES
GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP   = YES
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = NO
PREDEFINED             = "FUNC(type, memclass)=type" \
                         "VAR(type, memclass)=type" \
                         "CONST(type, memclass)=const type" \
                         "P2CONST(type, memclass, ptrclass)=const type *" \
                         "CONSTP2CONST(ptrtype, memclass, ptrclass)=ptrtype * const" \
                         DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS \
                         __declspec(x)= 
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = NO
HAVE_DOT               = YES
UML_LOOK               = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = svg
PLANTUML_JAR_PATH      = C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\plantuml\tools\plantuml.jar
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 500
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What are teh settings (different from the default settings, i.e. result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`)? is the given snippet code or comment or ...

Comment: Hi @albert, I am using doxygen 1.9.1. I have added the `doxygen -x Doxyfile`. That is the code I used to generate the interface in plantuml.

Comment: The current doxygen version is 1.9.5, so would be good to update. Why did you redefine the `startuml` command? The mentioned code snippet should be available as comment at the place in your comments where the other doxygen comments are. the `` \n `` should not be in the `ALIASES` but this should be `^^` (line counting etc.)

Comment: Probably my question is not clear enough. I am able to generate the interface using plantuml but I do not want to manually type `function1(void): void` and so on. I would like to directly grab them from the doxygen group. Will those aliases affecting this?

Comment: So my question is what is exactly in your source file and what is the language used? Maybe you should have a look at the `\snippet` command, might be hard to accomplish  though.